# SQL Server Query containing Regex

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex

I need to run a query against my SQL Server database using the below Regular Expression. This database exists on a development server, and I do not have access to enable CRL integration or create assemblies. Is there any other way to run a query that contains a Regular Expression against a SQL Server database?

If it is not possible, is it alternatively possible to formulate the below expression into a SQL Query?

The best solution I can come up with is to pull the table into a datatable using C#, do the necessary regex operations in C#, and then put it back into the database, but I'd really like to avoid that.

The regex: \d{4}(?=\D|$)(?<=(\D|^)\d{4}

EDIT: The SQL Query would need to take a string of any size with any alphanumeric characters in it and return an exactly 4 digit number. If there is a 5 digit number, it should not return 4 digits of that number.

Test Cases:

1. lis:xyz**1257**jd7=-1=-
2. &&12$*him**1763**&&whatwho
3. 12344567xx**1234**xy000000
4. 1874@45 &87 **9876** abc123

Returns:

1.1257

2.1763

3.1234

4.9876

Comment: what is the actual query you are trying to execute against the RegEx which appears to be validating Phone numbers.. please provide more information... I think that you should do a bit more googling on your end.. here is a good link to look at.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: Who needs Regex when you have the power of PATINDEX() and SUBSTRING() right at your fingertips?

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, I've read that article. In fact, it was the first in my google search and the first that I read. If you read my post, I specifically state that I cannot use CLR Integration, which is what is described in the article. I added more information about the query

Comment: How fast does this have to be? Like @TabAlleman said, you can parse strings in SQL and get same results as ones you would get with your regex.

Comment: @Tonci Performance is of no concern at all. I haven't been able to figure out a way with PatIndex or Substring that would satisfy my test cases above. I welcome any examples.

Comment: PatIndex and Substring are just the start!   There's WHILE loops, LEN() and ASC(), and to put it in the context of a query, all one needs do is create a UDF.

Comment: @TabAlleman Among the things I've tested, are the things you've listed. Lack of success led to my question here. Feel free to provide an example/answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for your specific test cases the following works

```
WITH Data AS (SELECT *
               FROM (VALUES 
('lis:xyz1257jd7=-1=-'),

('&&12$*him1763&&whatwho'),

('12344567xx1234xy000000'),

('56913546xx123xy000000'),

('1874@45 &87 9876 abc123'))x(val))

SELECT SUBSTRING (val,PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',val)+1,4)
  FROM Data
 WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',val) > 0
```

PATINDEX has a very limited regex functionality and as long as you can work with in its bounds its incredibly useful.

It can match characters `[]` Not match characters `[^]` and use the wild cards `_` for a single character and `%` for many characters. The syntax inside the `[]` is the same as most regexes IE. `[0-9]` is 0 through 9 and `[^0-9]` is any character that is not  0 through 9.

Then you need to use substring to actually get any string back.

EDIT:  As Pointed out by Tonci there was a small error.  Adding a where clause to catch a PATINDEX of 0 fixes the issue, `WHERE PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^0-9]%',val) > 0`

Comment: If no match is found, this returns first 4 characters of the string.

Comment: @Tonci Yep I forgot PATINDEX returned a 0 if it was not found.  The where clause will catch that case.

Comment: This works very well except for the situation where no 4 digit number exists, which I should have included in my test cases.

Comment: @user3087977 See the edit.  I added a where clause to take care of the case where a 4 digit string did not exist

Comment: There is one other scenario that will not work. If the 4 digit number is at the end of the string it will not work. So using your example ('lis:xyz127jd7=-1=-1234') would not find 1234.

Comment: @user3087977  Play around with it.  It should be a simple change to get it to work.